# Largest number in a text file

Tags: c

I need to find the largest number in a text file, including negative numbers, without using arrays or strings. The biggest problem for me is with negative numbers because the variable "number" is always returned to the value 0 which is greater than the negative numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main (){
  char c;
  int number = 0;
  int bigg = INT_MIN;
  int zn = 1;

  FILE *p = fopen ("first.txt", "r");
  if (p == NULL){
      printf("Can't opet first.exe!");
      return 1;
  }

  while((c = fgetc(p)) != EOF){
      if(c == '-')
      zn = -1;

      if(c >= '0' && c <= '9'){
          number *= 10;
          number += (c - '0');
      }
      else{
          number *= zn;
          if(number > bigg)
              bigg = number;
          number = 0;
      }
  }
  
  printf("Number is %d.\n", bigg);
  fclose(p);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the sample input? Why '0' (in single quotes?)

Comment: `int c;` ... otherwise you cannot distinguish between `EOF` and a valid character.

Comment: when `zn` becomes `-1` it will never ever swicth back to `1` .. or any other value :-)

Comment: Unrelated: `".exe"` is an unusual extension for text files.

Comment: You possibly forgot to reset `zn` to `1` at the point where you reset `number` to `0`.

Comment: @AvalSarri... `c - '0'` transforms the character `c` (`'0'`, `'1'`, ..., `'9'`) to the corresponding integer value (`0`, `1`, ..., `9`)

Comment: The simple input is like ("Number -45 is larger than -125 and -55."), and output need to be -45

Comment: Test if you understand your code. Looking at the code try to tell what will happen if the input file consists of several letters `'A'` only.

Comment: Why are you constructing the number yourself instead of using fscanf or fgets+sscanf? There are several potential bugs in your number parsing.

Comment: `-` is not a digit, so if you encounter this after another separator char, you'll negate the previous value (`0`) and compare it to `bigg`. You need to add logic for skipping chars until you reach a digit, `'-'` or the end of the file and then check the value you've just read.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is when you read a minus sign.
Let's assume `number` has `0` and `bigg` has `-45`

```
  if(c == '-')
  zn = -1;                 // ok, c is '-', zn is -1

  if(c >= '0' && c <= '9'){
      number *= 10;
      number += (c - '0');
  }
  else{                    // c is '-' so the else executes
      number *= zn;        // number is now 0 (0 * -1)
      if(number > bigg)    // comparing 0 with -45
          bigg = number;   // and bigg is now 0
      number = 0;
  }
```

---

Try

```
  if (c == '-') {
      zn = -1;                 // ok, c is '-', zn is -1
      continue;                // skip rest of the loop
  }
```